# Downloading zip file using web api results in corrupted file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code that downloads a zip file based on the URL and saves it to a folder. However, the downloaded file is corrupted. The downloaded file using the VBA code has a file size significantly lower than the actual file.
Below is the code I am using:

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
                    "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
                        ByVal pCaller As Long, _
                        ByVal szURL As String, _
                        ByVal szFileName As String, _
                        ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
                        ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "wininet.dll" Alias _
"DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" (ByVal lpszUrlName As String) As Long

Sub DownloadFile 
    Dim L as long
    L = URLDownloadToFile(0&, UrlFileName, DestinationFileName, 0&, 0&)

    If L = 0 Then
      Debug.Print "Download successful"
    Else
       Debug.Print "Download unsuccessful"
    End If
End Sub
```

`
The site that I am downloading the ZIP files requires a log-in, and I log-in to the site before I run the said VBA code.

Sample URL (not the true URL): https://www.samplewebsite.org/bsplink14/updownload/motorqcopia2.asp?vr=&name=VBGHFaz7243%5F20180424%5F0403%5FAirline%5FZCVDRFDBilling.zip&filtroread=true&extid=INDEFD1834262&rif=3373&s3s=47c7d4b47bc1c57cc4c6c29959dca0

Can you help me on this?

Comment: It must be something related to the http header. It should be set as binary data...

Comment: hello @decadenza, thank you for replying. can you show me how to do what you have suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you reference to MSXML, insert a class module, and in it the following code. Do the DownloadToFile only in case that function returns True, should work.

```
Public Function DoLoginByPost(URL As String, strUser As String, strPassword As String) As Boolean

    Dim xHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Dim sTICKER As String

    sTICKER = "user=" & strUser & "&pass=" & strPassword & "&logintype=login&pid=4&login=Login" 
    'Check this and edit accordingly by e.g. using the web developer tools in your browser when logging in regularly.
    'You should be able to identify what form data is being sent when loggin on.
    Set xHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    xHttp.Open "POST", URL
    xHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    xHttp.send sTICKER

    Do Until xHttp.READYSTATE = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    If xHttp.Status = 200 Then
        DoLoginByPost = True
        Else:   DoLoginByPost = False
    End If

End Function



'After receiving "TRUE", alter your original code to:

Set xHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
xHttp.Open "Get", UrlFileName, False
xHttp.send

Do Until xHttp.ReadyState = 4
  DoEvents
Loop

Open DestinationFileName For Binary As #1
   Put #1, , xHttp.responseBody
Close #1
```

Comment: Hello @EarlyBird2, thank you for your reply. How will I edit the sTICKER variable? Should I replace the "user=" and "&pass=" with the input name based on the site?

Comment: Hi @mean_, if you click the login button to your web page in a browser, you can either see something like an URL in the status bar of the browser which is being sent to the web page. Try to figure out what it is, use web developer tools in Firefox e.g. and adjust the sTICKER accordingly.

Comment: apologies for the late reply. I have managed to get the appropriate sTICKER for the site, and your function returns TRUE. However, the file that I have downloaded is still corrupted, file size is less than the actual size.

Comment: I found this link, seems related to your issue: <https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/790043-download-zip-files-from-website-in-specified-folder.html>  I have edited my answer above accordingly, pls check.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Actually, it is from those sites that I got my code.

Comment: Apologies if I was not that clear. I meant, in those references that you mentioned I got the code I posted above, in which the downloaded files are corrupted.

Comment: Ah, no worries, so no success yet?